# gitpython - how to check if a remote branch exists?

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm new to gitpython and haven't been able to find a reference to this anywhere. What I'm looking to do is something like:

```
If remote branch name exists:
  do something
else:
  do something else
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#switching-branches and https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly

Answer (score 4):

GitPython has references to all the branches. A user can iterate to check if the branch is part of that reference or not.

To print all the branches use this as reference:

```
for ref in repo.references:
    print("Branch Name is: ", ref.name)
```

Similarly for your purpose, if you can do something like

```
for ref in repo.references:
    if branchName == ref.name:
        Do likely something
    else:
        Do unlikely something
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest seems to be:

```
allBranches = git.Git().branch("-all").split()
"<testedBranch>" in allBranches
>>> true/false
```

- this embeds the branches within all the standard techniques of a sequence protocol

Answer (score 0):

This may not work, but give it a shot let me know how it goes:

```
does_exist = True
try:
    repo.git.checkout('branch_name')
except repo.exc.GitCommandError:
    does_exist = False

print(does_exist)
```

This may also work but give it a try:

```
repo.git.rev_parse('--verify', 'branch_name')
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Muadh! I was able to get this to work:

```
try:
    repo.git.checkout( 'origin/' + branch_name, b=branch_name )
except:
    repo.git.checkout( 'origin/master', b=branch_name )
```